# How to loop through $_POST passing each post field as a parameter to a function?Edit

Tags: php, post, foreach

I am just representing algorithmically what i want to achieve using a foreach loop and the $_POST array in php.

```
    function check_fields($_POST)
{
 // provide $_post['field1'],$_post['field2']..so on

  foreach($_POST as $_POST['FIELD 1-N'] 
{

 isvalid($_POST['FIELD1 - N']);
}
}
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to ask...

EDIT: $_POST['FIELD1'], $_POST['FIELD1']  and so on are variable names that are passed to isvalid() function.   What The isvalid() function does is use isset() and empty to check if the variable contains a value...

Comment: Like a puzzle, no understand..

Comment: Question edited for additional information...

Comment: So, you need to check if all fields (field1 .. xx) are present and non-empty?

Comment: @thaJeztah - yes...  what's making it complex for me is all these fields are $_post fields...

Comment: Thanks all, I'm looking into what works and I'll let you know later...

Answer (score 2):

With `foreach`, you don't have to know the names of the keys in the array.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $field) {
    isvalid($field);
}
```

`$key` contains the names like "field1", "field2" and so on while `$field` contains the value inside the `$_POST` array. The foreach loop will then run the function `invalid()` on each of the field value.

To check if the field values are set:

```
// Sample $_POST array
$_POST = array(
    "field1" => "", // this is not set
    "field2" => "data"
);
foreach($_POST as $key => $field) {
    // You can check if it is empty using foreach alone
    if (strlen($field) > 0) {
        // this field is set
    } else {
        // this field is not set
    }
}
```

You can use `empty()` as well but it treats `"0"` as empty so be careful.

Comment: Do 'field1', 'field2' represent variable names on which i can run an isset() to check if these variables were set... otherwise please see edited question...I think I tried something what you are suggesting and it didn't work previously...

Comment: @user481913 You can't use `isset()` to check those variables since they are set by the time the form is submitted, just that those variables could be empty. Check the updated answer for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue) 
{
 isvalid($fieldValue);
}
```

Comment: Try for what? "Try this" is an answer?

Answer (score 1):

One sample loop to get both the array keys & values:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
{

    isvalid( $key, $value );

}
```

... so you need to change your `isvalid()` function to accept two parameters if you need to get the `field1`, `field2`, etc.

**EDITED**

```
$errors = array();    

foreach( $_POST as $key => $value )
    if ( empty( $value ) ) $errors[] = $key;

if ( !empty( $errors ) )
    echo 'You have errors on: <pre>' . print_r( $errors, true ) . '</pre>';
```

... you can cancel the submit if `$errors` is not empty.

Comment: What is happening inside `isvalid()`? If you just want to do checks as per your edited qestion, you can do it like my edited answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are tyring to create a validation function named as `isvalid`;

```
function isvalid($input) {
    return ('' !== trim($input));
}

// loop
$errors = arrray();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!isvalid($value)) {
        $errors[] = "$key not be empty!";
    }
}
print_r($errors);
```

Meanwhile, if `$_POST` input is not isset, then it won't be in foreach.